# $\frac{4x + 1 }{2} = 2 x-3$. Solve for $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot (4 x+1) = 2 x-3$$

I think this is unsolvable. I can not for the life of me figure out a way to solve this for $x$.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\frac{4x+1}{2}=2x-3$$

Then

$$4x+1=4x-6$$

Thus

$$1\neq-6$$

No solution exists, these are parallel lines.

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to be sure. The question asks to solve for x only. I was going insane.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, $\frac{4x+ 1}{2}= 2x+ \frac{1}{2}$.  If that were equal to 2x- 3 for any value of x, then, subtracting 2x from both sides of $2x+ \frac{1}{2}= 2x- 3$, we get $\frac{1}{2}= -3$ which is, of course, not true.  Again, there is no value of x satisfying that equation.